# Conditional convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n(\theta))_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables with value in $\mathbb{R}^q$ indexed by a parameter $\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^q$. Suppose that for all $\theta \in \Theta$:
\begin{align*}
X_n(\theta) \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1) \quad \text{($\star$)}
\end{align*}
in distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now let $\nu$ be a probability measure such that $\nu(\Theta) = 1$. If we let $\theta \sim \nu$, does ($\star$) still hold?

Comment: Does the entire sequence $X_n$ use the same $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit to reflect.